# UDP messaging cannot success get it in computer2

Tags: java, udp

I have the problem i using UDP connection to send 3 messages to the computer2, it can only get the last messages only in the computer 2

```
String service = "deposit";     //send service
byteSend = service.getBytes();
sendPacket.setData(byteSend);
sendPacket.setAddress(destAdd);
sendPacket.setPort(destPort);
otherBranch.send(sendPacket);

byteSend1 = accNo.getBytes();    //send accNo
sendPacket.setData(byteSend1);
sendPacket.setAddress(destAdd);
sendPacket.setPort(destPort);
otherBranch.send(sendPacket);

byteSend2 = depositAmount.getBytes();  //send depositAmount
sendPacket.setData(byteSend2);
sendPacket.setAddress(destAdd);
sendPacket.setPort(destPort);
otherBranch.send(sendPacket);
```

after that the computer2 have this code to receive:

```
myServer.receive(packetReceive);
clientMessage = new String(packetReceive.getData(),0,packetReceive.getLength());
System.out.println("Service: "+clientMessage);

myServer.receive(packetReceive);
accNo = new String(packetReceive.getData(),0,packetReceive.getLength());
System.out.println("accNo: "+accNo);

myServer.receive(packetReceive);
depositAmount = new String(packetReceive.getData(),0,packetReceive.getLength());
System.out.println("depositAmount: "+depositAmount);
```

How come the output only can get my last value which is depositAmount only?

Comment: additional Q, how come the same code i using first time to run no problem, but second time i running, it only can retrieve last value, wait for a while run again, it successful to get again?

Comment: UDP is unreliable. You have to implement the reliability yourself if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has no transmit pacing. With TCP, the stack does transmit pacing for you. With UDP, it's your responsibility.

You need to write code to detect dropped datagrams and retransmit them. UDP does not guarantee message delivery. That's the application's job.

If you need everything TCP does, and yet you choose to use UDP, you have to implement all of it yourself.

This includes:

1. Transmit pacing.
2. Exponential backoff.
3. Dropped datagram detection and retransmission.
4. Duplicate datagram detection.
5. Out of order reception handling.
6. Corrupt datagram detection.

If you don't want to do all this stuff, use TCP. Then the stack does it all for you.

Comment: can i know that how to make sure if i compulsory want to use UDP, and i want to make UDP successful 100% send to destination? any keyword or sample code i can refer?

Comment: Unfortunately, you really do need to implement all six of the things I mentioned above. If performance doesn't matter, you can just send the datagram and wait for an acknowledgement. If you don't get one in a reasonable amount of time, send the datagram again. Repeat until you do get an acknowledgement. The other end will have to acknowledge every datagram and acknowledge duplicates (in case its acknowledge doesn't get through). (Look at [tftp](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1350.txt). It works this way.)

Comment: I could probably give you more helpful advice if I understood why you were using UDP and what your priorities are. (For example, is performance important? Is latency? Is throughput?)

Comment: because this is an assignment for my college work, UDP is the question required, no any priorities require, just I can receive successful the message then is enough, can you give me a sample code for 2 file and it receive 3 values at the same time?

Comment: Take a look at simple TFFP [servers](http://tftpserver.blogspot.com/) and [clients](https://github.com/vilius/tftp/tree/master/java/src).